Can't use C in R notebook
I'm new to R and trying to get a C function running inside a R notebook. Therefore I composed a .Rmd file within RStudio which contains the following code chunk and error:

I also printed the available engines and "c" is one of them. Running R CMD SHLIB <name>.c via the terminal works just fine. R as well as RStudio were installed using Homebrew.
